# Como ler vários valores em uma única linha no Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Como eu faço para ler mais de um valor em uma única linha? Pois o exercício que eu estou fazendo diz o seguinte:

> o arquivo de entrada contém duas linhas de dados. Em cada linha haverá 3 valores, respectivamente dois inteiros e um valor com 2 casas decimais. Por exemplo:
>
> 12 1 5.30
>
> 16 2 5.10

Eu tentei fazer o exercício utilizando o método:
`stdin.readLineSync()`, mas ele sempre pula para a próxima linha.

```
  int codigoPeca1 = int.tryParse(stdin.readLineSync());
  int numeroPeca1 = int.tryParse(stdin.readLineSync());
  double valorUnitarioPeca1 = double.tryParse(stdin.readLineSync());

  int codigoPeca2 = int.tryParse(stdin.readLineSync());
  int numeroPeca2 = int.tryParse(stdin.readLineSync());
  double valorUnitarioPeca2 = double.tryParse(stdin.readLineSync());
```

Já pesquisei e não encontrei nada relacionado em Dart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `split()` que quebra a *String* de acordo com o separador que você informar e transforma em uma `List`.

Assim você só precisa recurperar apenas uma vez o valor e depois trata ele para ser utilizado nas outras variáveis.

Segue um exemplo, adeque para o seu caso onde você recupera o valor da entrada dos valores:

```
void main() {
  // Aqui seria o stdin.readLineSync()
  final dadosEntrada = "12 1 5.30";
  
  // Quebra os valores em itens de um array a cada espaço encontrado
  // Retorno: [12, 1, 5.30]
  final List<String> valoresSeparados = dadosEntrada.split(" ");
  
  // Pega o item respectivo do array e transforma em int ou double, retornando 0 (zero) caso não consiga converter corretamente
  int codigoPeca1 = int.tryParse(valoresSeparados[0]) ?? 0;
  int numeroPeca1 = int.tryParse(valoresSeparados[1]) ?? 0;
  double valorUnitarioPeca1 = double.tryParse(valoresSeparados[2]) ?? 0.0;
  
  print("codigoPeca1: $codigoPeca1 || numeroPeca1: $numeroPeca1 || valorUnitarioPeca1: $valorUnitarioPeca1");
}
```

Obs.: Você pode rodar esse código no [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true) para ver como funciona.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda Matheus! Estudei o código e consegui resolver o meu problema.